# Finding the PGF for the Immigration Birth Death Proccess

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, generating-functions

> Let $X$ be the stochastic process corresponding the the number of
>   cells.
>
> $X \rightarrow X+1$ at rate $I$ due to immigration
>
> $X \rightarrow X+1$ at rate $X B$ due to birth (X cells, each giving
>   birth are rate B)
>
> $X \rightarrow X-1$ at rate $XD$ due to death (X cells, each dying at
>   rate D)
>
> I need to derive the following PGF: $$F(z)=(\frac{B-D}{Bz-D})^{I/B}$$

Let $\pi_i$ be the long-time proportion of having $i$ cells. Then let $F(z)=\sum_{i=0} z^i \pi_i$

I build the following relationship using the detailed balance equations:

$$(I+iB)\pi_i=(i+1)D \pi_{i+1}$$

Then multiply both sides by $z^i$ and sum over $i$ to get:

\begin{align*}
& I \sum \pi_i z^i+ \sum iB\pi_i z^i = \sum (i+1)D \pi_{i+1} z^i\\
& I F(z) +  B z \dot F(z) = D F(z)\\ 
& \dot F(z) = (D-I)F(z)/Bz\\
& df/dz=(D-I)F(z)/Bz\\
& \int df/F(z)=\int (D-I)dz/Bz\\
& \log F(z) = (D-I)/B log z\\
& F =\exp{(D-I)/B} z \\
\end{align*}

Subject to inital conditions $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=1$

Comment: It should be "dying at rate D", not "dying at rate B", I presume (D, not B)

Comment: The step $$I F(z) +  B z \dot F(z) = D F(z)$$ should read $$I F(z) +  B z \dot F(z) = D \dot F(z)$$ then the rest should proceed smoothly.

Comment: @Did thanks a lot, It worked out great.